# How to set ajax header with amp-form

Tags: amp-html, amp-form

There are some codes in my old code.

```
 $.ajaxSetup({headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN':$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')}});
```

How can I do this using amp-form?

Comment: Do not use html kind of tags, use SO formats

Comment: Could you please clarify what is SO formates? Thanks.

Comment: Yes sure, use https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I've updated the question.